# SQL Snowflake: Value does not show up in SELECT * search but does show up when included in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, select, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, where-clause

Hello and thank you in advance!

I have a SQL query that returns a list of customers for a course ID where the status is 'active'.  I noticed the total count was incorrect and that there were a few missing customers who do not show up in the result list.  When I include those customers in the WHERE clause, they do show up.  If they satisfy all other WHERE filters, shouldn't they show up without being directly referenced?

**Query where the specific customer does NOT show up in the result list**

```
 SELECT * FROM COURSES_ACTIVE
 WHERE COURSE_ID = '123aaaBBB'
 AND COURSE_STATUS = 'Active';
```

**Query where the specific customer DOES show up in the result list**

```
 SELECT * FROM COURSES_ACTIVE
 WHERE COURSE_ID = '123aaaBBB'
 AND COURSE_STATUS = 'Active'
 AND CUSTOMER_ID = '555cccDDD';
```

**Things I have tried**

Originally I thought maybe it was something to do with the fact that IDs needed to be case sensitive and maybe in a previous SELECT statement things were getting combined incorrectly with GROUP BY.  I made sure all IDs were COLLATE("CUSTOMER_ID ", 'binary').  I have confirmed in all previous queries the CUSTOMER_IDs do show up without including them in the WHERE clause.

I have gotten the correct CUSTOMER_IDs to show up when I stick a "::VARCHAR" after the SELECT CUSTOMER_ID::VARCHAR, but as that is not case sensitive, I am worried I again won't have all IDs.

If I stick "::BINARY" at the end of the SELECT CUSTOMER_ID::BINAY, I get the error "The following string is not a legal hex-encoded value: '888ooo000'"  <--this fills with a random CUSTOMER_ID

**Full code**

```
WITH COURSES_ALL AS (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
                            COURSE_ID,
                            MAX(COURSE_EXPIRATION_DATE) CURRENT_EXPIRATION_DATE
                     FROM DATABASE
                     GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID,
                              COURSE_ID

  -- Course get new row entries so I use MAX to make sure I am only working with the most recent entry.  
  -- I have confirmed that if I run my query here, all CUSTOMER_IDs show up.

COURSES_ACTIVE AS (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
                          COURSE_ID,
                          CURRENT_EXPIRATION_DATE,
                          CASE
                              WHEN CURRENT_EXPIRATION_DATE < '2024-01-31' THEN 'Inactive'
                              WHEN CURRENT_EXPIRATION_DATE >= '2024-01-31' THEN 'Active'
                          END  COURSE_STATUS,
                          FROM COURSES_ALL)

 SELECT * FROM COURSES_ACTIVE
 WHERE COURSE_ID = '123aaaBBB'
 AND COURSE_STATUS = 'Active';
 --   AND CUSTOMER_ID = '555cccDDD'; //adding this line back in results in the customer showing up in the results
```

Comment: How many rows are returned in your first query? Sorry to ask, but are you sure you downloaded all and not just the first n-rows?

Comment: Does using `ILIKE` for case-insensitve comparison help(assuming that columns does not contain wildcards like `_` or `%`): `WHERE COURSE_ID ILIKE '123aaaBBB'
 AND COURSE_STATUS ILIKE 'Active'
 AND CUSTOMER_ID ILIKE '555cccDDD';`?

Comment: @Isolated 216 rows when I run the query and my Output window is set to show 500.  I did scroll to the bottom just to be safe

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda I need the IDs to be case sensitive.  We have IDs like 123aaaBBB and 123AAAbbb

Comment: Could you provide actual reproducible example with table structure and sample dummy data?

Comment: Does the behavior change if you fix/change your second CTE? You seemingly have the wrong year (2024). And without ELSE in the case expression, that might be a problem combined with the gap in years.

Comment: Is there a typo in your CASE statement or did you mean not to assign values to records in 2023? I’m guessing the issue may be due to having nulls in this calculated column - I always add a default value to CASE statements to make it easy to identify issues

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda Of the 48 customer IDs, 30 show up when I run the query and I am not sure why some are excluded or some throw the hex-encoded error when I use ::binary.  I hesitate to share actual IDs since some doe show up in internal account URLs

Comment: Yes, sorry, there was a typo.  The default value is NULL and I fill it in with a date, if applicable, in another query.

Comment: This probably isn't the issue, but what happens if you provide an alias that's different from the original column name `CURRENT_EXPIRATION_DATE`, and then reference that in the second CTE?

Comment: Can you try replacing MAX(COURSE_EXPIRATION_DATE) this with ifnull(MAX(COURSE_EXPIRATION_DATE),’1900-01-01’) and then see if it makes any difference

Comment: @Kathmandude That actually worked for the specific customer who was originally missing!  Now I have 37 entries (up from 30 before), but should have 48.

Comment: @ADITYA PAWAR I did but still am getting the same 37 customers instead of the full 48

Comment: @Haley What expiration dates do those remaining customers have?

Comment: @Kathmandude, all customers now have a date of 1900-01-01, 2024-01-31, 2024-01-31, or 2025-01-31.  If the date was NULL, I filled it with the 1900.  Else it pulls from whatever data they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this in the future, turns out our source data was corrupted with incorrect data types.  Once our admin reset and refreshed all IDs, they now work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the date and course I suggest using a bind variables to make the query more flexible. Also, in the current query you are not filtering in the first CTE, this seems wasteful, and there isn't much point in calculating 'Inactive' if you are just going to filter out those rows.

So instead I suggest:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATE = '2024-01-31';
DECLARE @COURSE_ID VARCHAR = '123aaaBBB';

SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, COURSE_ID, MAX(COURSE_EXPIRATION_DATE) CURRENT_EXPIRATION_DATE
FROM DATABASE
WHERE COURSE_ID COLLATE 'en-cs' = @COURSE_ID COLLATE 'en-cs'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, COURSE_ID
HAVING MAX(COURSE_EXPIRATION_DATE) >= @DATE;
```

If you don't need to enforce the case sensitive collation that can be removed. Alternatively, use a case insensitive collation if that is required.